# Regex calendar validation

Tags: java, regex, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a program where the user enters a date(any date), for example **29-Jul-1995**. The program should match the date format and validate if this date is correct or not.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Review1_Main {

public static Pattern pattern;
public static Matcher matcher;

// DATE_PATTERN is a format for user input
private static final Pattern DATE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-(^[a-zA-Z]+$)-((19|20)\\d\\d)");

// Date format validation
public static boolean dateValidation(String date) {

matcher = pattern.matcher(date);

if(matcher.matches()) {
  matcher.reset();

  if (matcher.find()) {
    int day = 01;
    String month = "Jan";
    int year = 2000;

    if(day == 31 && !month.equals("Apr") || !month.equals("Jun") ||
                    !month.equals("Sep") || !month.equals("Nov")) {
      return false;
    } else if(month.equals("Feb")) {
      // LEAP year validation
      if (year % 4 == 0) {
        if (day == 30 || day == 31) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        if (day == 29 || day == 30 || day == 31) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }// end of year % 4
    } else {
      return true;
    }// end of day.equals
  } else {
    return false;
  } // end of matcher.find
} else {
  return false;
}// end of matcher.matcher

}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   String dateInput = "29-Jul-1995";
   dateValidation(dateInput);
 }

} // end of class
```

But for some reason, when I try to compile it, I always get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Review1_Main.dateValidation(Review1_Main.java:22)
    at Review1_Main.main(Review1_Main.java:73)
```

Where Line 22 is:

```
matcher = pattern.matcher(date);
```

and Line 73 is:

```
dateValidation(dateInput);
```

My apologize about my grammar.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Java 8 by any chance?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis yeah

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html (This can make your life a lot easier). Plenty of examples on SO as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initialising `pattern` in the constructor but using it in a static method `dateValidation`. Unless you have constructed an object using `new` before calling the method then the static field will not be initialised (hence the null pointer exception).

The solution is to turn your pattern into a constant rather than compiling it in the constructor:

```
private static final Pattern DATE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("...");
```

And then use the constant (rather than `pattern`) to create the `Matcher`:

```
Matcher matcher = DATE_PATTERN.match(dateInput);
```

You don't need the `pattern` or `matcher` static variables.

Note that there's really no reason for you to be using a static method. Better would be to call this a `DateValidator` class and make the validation method an instance method. The pattern can still be a constant.

Comment: Still getting an error, but your answer fixed my first error
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Review1_Main.dateValidation(Review1_Main.java:22)
        at Review1_Main.main(Review1_Main.java:73)`

Comment: @S.Anthony assuming your code has now changed there's no way I can help with your new error as I don't know what code is on line 22.

Comment: My bad, I've updated the code and THANK YOU very much for your help

Answer (score -1):

With Java 8:

```
String dateInput = "01-Feb-2016";

List<String> months = new ArrayList<String>();
months.add("Jan");
months.add("Feb");
months.add("Mar");
months.add("Apr");
months.add("May");
months.add("Jun");
months.add("Jul");
months.add("Aug");
months.add("Sep");
months.add("Oct");
months.add("Nov");
months.add("Dec");

boolean dateIsValid = true;
try
{
    String [] vals = dateInput.split("-");
    int day = Integer.parseInt(vals[0]);
    int mon = months.indexOf(vals[1]) + 1;
    int year = Integer.parseInt(vals[2]);
    LocalDate.of(year, mon, day);
}
catch (DateTimeException e)
{
    dateIsValid = false;
}
System.out.println("Date is valid: " + dateIsValid);
```